# Doubly LinkedList addLast Java

Tags: java, коллекции, linked-list

Нужно реализовать метод addLast в LinkedList, и он у меня не работает от слова совсем.
Сам метод:

```
public void addLast(int data){
    Node newNode = new Node(data); 
    newNode.previous = lastNode;   
    lastNode = newNode;  
}
```

Класс Node:

```
public class Node {

    public int data;
    public Node next;
    public Node previous;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next=null;
        this.previous=null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data: " + data ;
    }
}
```

Конструктор в классе LinkedList:

```
public void LinkedList() {        
    firstNode = null;  
    lastNode = null;
}
```

Если сможете, подскажите где можно найти информацию о том как работает этот список. Я разобралась в том, как сделать список с одной ссылкой, но очень сильно не понимаю, как реализовать список с двумя ссылками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информацию можно найти в хорошей книге Роберта Лафоре "Структуры данных и алгоритмы в Java". Там целая глава посвящена ЛинкедЛист'у(в т.ч. и двусвязному) и его реализации на практике.